# LWC Cannot select value on lightning-textarea

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Steps

1. Type "Some text" in the text field
2. Click Save button

Actual Result:
The component refreshes with what you see now: "SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }"
And the console logs print Proxy objects with no value "Some text"

Expected Result:
It should refresh with "Some text"

[image]

I think there is something I'm not understanding about locker and/or selectors after reading many articles on both topics. I'd especially like to understand why I'm getting Proxy objects instead of the lightning-textarea?

```
saveChecklistState() {

    const SUCCESSEVENT = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: 'Saved',
      message: 'Your checklist has been saved.',
      variant: 'success',
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(SUCCESSEVENT);

    this.activityIdsForTracker = [...this.template
                                  .querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
                                  .filter(element => element.checked)
                                  .map(element => element.dataset.id);
    
    console.log('querySelector: ',this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea"));

    this.mandatedActivityNotes = [this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea")];
    console.log('this.mandatedActivityNotes: ',this.mandatedActivityNotes);

    updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes(
      {siteSurveyId:this.siteSurveyId, 
       activityIdsForTracker:this.activityIdsForTracker,
       mandatedActivityNotes: this.mandatedActivityNotes,
      });
  }
```

---

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>

    <div class="slds-form-element slds-m-left_medium slds-m-right_medium">
      <!--label class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_small" for="textarea-id-01">Mandated Activity Notes</label>
      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <textarea id="textarea-id-01" placeholder="Provide your reasoning here…" class="slds-textarea">
          {mandatedActivityNotes}
        </textarea>
      </div-->
      <lightning-textarea 
        name="mandatedNotes" 
        label="Mandated Activity Notes" 
        value={mandatedActivityNotes}
      ></lightning-textarea>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error from your updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes action passing the incorrect property type.

```
this.mandatedActivityNotes = [this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea")];
```

This is getting the component itself, but you want the value property to pass to your method.

```
this.mandatedActivityNotes = [this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea").value];
```

Regarding getting the proxy objects, I usually use JSON.stringify() to get a more readable output.

Comment: Thanks CyberJus. That did it. I'm an Apex dev trying to ramp up on frontend. Thanks for your patience with my elementary question here. This fix exposed another bug. I'll post it separately next.